# send refresh request to page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to refresh a page as soon as a processs on the server is completed. I wouldn't know where to begin or where to start my search.

I have to following scheme, which works perfectly:

1. A user uploads a file to the server via a website
2. The server checks whether the file is valid and copies the file to another folder.
3. In the other folder the file has to wait to be processed by a program (Filemaker Server) that is scheduled to run every 1 minute (or whatever interval).
4. After the program has finished processing the file it marks a MySQL database entry with "0 no error" or whatever was returned by the process.

So far so good. I would like the user of the website to know when the process is ended. I already have a timer that counts down to 0, which is the amount of seconds until the processing starts. The user is then presented with the text "processing started".

Now, I would like to send a refresh request to the client browser at the moment the processing ends. This should be either some batch file command or a mysql function; I really don't have a clue. I did try `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1";URL=home.php">`, but the refreshes (every 1 second or any other interval) are not acceptable, because the user has to upload a file through a form which is unfortunately cleared whenever a refresh takes place. (This is not a problem when a server request would refresh the page, because only one upload process can take place at a time.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on this matter!

Comment: Not sure if it's right for your specific application... Upon submission, before you output anything to the page, you can use PHPs `header` to redirect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever read on AJAX?

I think a [jQuery Ajax Upload](https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Ajax-Upload) is everything you need of. In the server-side you get the script, treat it, upload it, insert into the database some information regarding it, and then you inform the client-side the upload is over and the insertion has been successfully.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript:

```
<script rel=JavaScript>window.location="home.php";</script>
```

Comment: I already used that to display the "processing started" message after the timer's hit 0. How would I send this request again at the moment the processing is done?

Answer (score 0):

I finally settled for using AJAX as per Ivo's suggestion. It is fairly easy to use! Thanks!